# Sending a Email using Poco Library C++ (Gmail)

Tags: c++, email, exception, poco

I tried this code but I get SMTP Exception, What could I do?
I tried changing the login id and password making sure they are the correct so.

If anyone knows what I can try to make it work I would be very grateful.

```
// compile with: g++ -Wall -O3 Email.cc -lPocoNet -lPocoFoundation -o Email && ./Email

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Net/SMTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/MailMessage.h>
#include <string>

using namespace Poco::Net;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::string Username = "email_id";
    std::string Password = "password";

    std::string Receiver = "receiver@gmail.com";
    std::string Name = "Charles";

    std::string Subject = "Hello!";
    std::string Content = "TEXT OF THE EMAIL";

    try
    {
        MailMessage msg;

        msg.addRecipient(MailRecipient(MailRecipient::PRIMARY_RECIPIENT, Receiver, Name));

        msg.setSender(Username);
        msg.setSubject(Subject);
        msg.setContent(Content);

        SMTPClientSession smtp("smtp.gmail.com");
        smtp.login(SMTPClientSession::AUTH_LOGIN, Username, Password);
        smtp.sendMessage(msg);
        smtp.close();
        std::cerr << "Sent mail successfully!" << std::endl;
    }
    catch (std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to send mail: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: what exactly is the exception that its giving you?

Comment: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
SSL Exception
SSL Exception: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number